# As Goliath, did Clint Barton ever take advantage of his Hawkeye skills?

Tags: marvel, hawkeye

In my quest to read all Hulk comics, I recently read [Avengers #88](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_88) and [Sub-Mariner #35](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sub-Mariner_Vol_1_35).

In both these comics, Clint Barton makes an appearance as [Goliath](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Goliath). This is the same Clint Barton better known as Hawkeye. I did a bit of research, and found that he decided to start using Pym particles as Goliath so that he could still rescue Black Widow after his bow was broken in a crash in [Avengers #63](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_63).

I don't know how long he continued as Goliath, but it was at least these 25 issues. Although Barton is a good tactician and has hand-to-hand training from Captain America, the main things he brings to the table are nearly superhuman perception and accuracy. It would seem strange for him to just throw out those abilities.

So, as Goliath, was Barton still able to take advantage of his Hawkeye abilities? Did he make a habit of shooting or throwing things with extreme accuracy?

I'd accept a specific example, or indications of a general trend.

Comment: It turns out telephone poles don't make good arrows, so no.

Comment: @Jeff The Hawkeye in Avengers Assemble is extremely adept at throwing things, including random rocks off the ground. I'm thinking of that more than carrying a huge bow.

Comment: Avengers Assemble is based off of the Ultimates (Ultimate Marvel universe) Hawkeye, not the Marvel 616 Hawkeye who became Goliath.  Ultimate Hawkeye has a different skillset than 616 Hawkeye.  I've never seen a reference to 616 Hawkeye as having the same throwing skills, just amazing archery skills and athleticism.

Comment: @Jeff Well that's good to know. Probably a 'no', then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He did, in fact, in [Avengers #65](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_65), "The Swordsman Strikes!" where he cobbled together a giant makeshift bow and arrow out of some construction materials while fighting Swordsman.

[image]

Comment: Looks like he made that bow in less than a second. That's crazier than the shot.

Answer (score 2):

Two other instances (beyond Crimebuster's example):

*Avengers* #86 (1970), where Goliath uses Hyperion as an arrow!
[image]

*Avengers* #99 (1971) This other moment is a little questionable. Right on the cusp of identities.  Clint is giving up being Goliath, but he is still wearing the costume when he uses this makeshift archery rig.
[image]